# Django run models.py from command line

Tags: django, django-models

I was wondering how one can exercise the models outside the Django
`manage.py` control.

i.e. given the following combination of the tutorial parts how would I be able to just `python models.py`.

```
# models.py
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')

class Choice(models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    from polls.models import Poll, Choice 
    print Poll.objects.all()
    import datetime
    p = Poll(question="What's up?", pub_date=datetime.datetime.now())
    p.save()
    print p.id
    print p.question
    print p.pub_date
    p.pub_date = datetime.datetime(2007, 4, 1, 0, 0)
    p.save()
    print Poll.objects.all()
```

I tried setting up `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = ...` to my settings file, no joy.
and then changed that to be this at the top

```
import imp
imp.find_module('settings') # Assumed to be in the same directory.

from django.core.management import setup_environ
import settings
setup_environ(settings)
```

but to no avail.

Any ideas would be grateful received it seems such a typical use case.

---

I appreciate that Django has a big ecosystem behind it but I was expecting some form of:

```
set-up-env
do-stuff
```

without the need to write mange scripts.

Comment: http://www.b-list.org/weblog/2007/sep/22/standalone-django-scripts/

Comment: Wait... you tried to tell Django where to find the settings file *inside the settings file*? How exactly were you expecting that to work?

Comment: Did I ? I alternated the two approaches but I didn't make that clear.

Comment: The standalone scripts may be useful I'll have to read up on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

run this from project root dir :- it works :D

```
import os

import sys

from django.conf import settings
os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'settings'

sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__)) + '/../')

from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):

        question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
        pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
        class Meta:
           app_label = #app_name
```

*your second class*

```
if __name__ == "__main__":

         print Poll.objects.all()
         import datetime
         p = Poll(question="What's up?", pub_date=datetime.datetime.now())
         p.save()
         print p.id
         print p.question
         print p.pub_date
         p.pub_date = datetime.datetime(2007, 4, 1, 0, 0)
         p.save()
         print Poll.objects.all()
```